# Neo takes 13 seconds to count 0 nodes

Tags: neo4j

I've been experimenting with Neo4j for a while now. I've been inserting data from the medical terminology database SNOMED in order to experiment with a large dataset.

While experimenting, I have repeatedly inserted and then deleted around 450,000 nodes. I'm finding Neo's performance to be somewhat unsatisfactory. For example, I have just removed all nodes from the database. Running the query:

```
match (n) return count (n)
```

takes 13085 ms to return 0 nodes.

I'm struggling to understand why it might take this time to count 0 things. Does Neo retain some memory of nodes that are deleted? Is it in some way hobbled by the fact that I have inserted and removed large amounts of nodes in the past? Might it perform better if I delete the data directory instead of deleting all nodes with Cypher?

Or is there some twiddling with memory allocation and so forth that might help?

I'm running it on an old-ish laptop running Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2):

It's partly due to neo4j's store format. Creating new nodes or relationships assigns them ids, where ids are actual offsets into the store files. Deleting a node or relationship marks that record as not in use in the store file. Looking at all nodes is done by scanning the node store file to spot records that are in use.

Comment: Is this permanent? Is there anything I can do to remove the 'phantom' deleted nodes and speed things up?